# Robustness Principle and APIs

Tags: api, rest

Should the [Robustness Principle](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle) (*Be conservative in what you do, be liberal in what you accept from others*) be applied to APIs?

As an example, I've seen APIs that handle user parameters, such as *limit*, in one of two ways:

Where *limit* is the maximum number of results to return, if a user enters in the letter 'x' for *limit*, some APIs throw a validation error since the input wasn't numeric, other APIs simply fall back to the default limit (ex: 1000).

What would you recommend in terms of how to handle such user input? Throw a useful and descriptive validation error, or gracefully sanitize the input and continue with the request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does not make a large difference either way, as long as you clearly document what you're going to do. Your behaviour in a situation like this would largely depend on the specific field and type of data. For instance, you can default to a number like 1000 for numeric values, but what will you do with an invalid timestamp?

For a limit value I would degrade to a default (whatever value you would use if it wasn't included at all), however you should clearly document how your API will behave for each field (whether its required, its default values, etc). If it's clearly documented, your users will (should) be able to use it properly either way.